# Oracle data-source configuration for Spring

Tags: oracle, spring, datasource

In the Spring framework, how is an Oracle data-source configured?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In the *context.xml* file:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
    <property name="dataSourceName" value="ds"/>
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:<port_num>:<SID>"/>
    <property name="user" value="dummy_user"/>
    <property name="password" value="dummy_pwd"/>
</bean>
```

**Example of URL:** jdbc:oracle:thin:@abc.def.ghi.com:1234:TEAM4

Answer (score 13):

**1. Since Oracle JDBC Driver is not in Maven repository**, download it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html
(for example Oracle Database 12.1.0.2 JDBC Driver) and add this driver through Maven command as follows:

**(in my case)**

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=D:\Downloads\Java\ojdbc7.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar
```

**2. Add in pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
     <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
     <version>12.1.0.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

**3. Add in application.properties file**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
spring.datasource.username=hr
spring.datasource.password=hr
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Answer (score 6):

Note you may want to add to the above that the Oracle driver does not have an open source licence so it will not be in the Maven central repository.  You'll have to add it to your local repo.

To do this:
Get the driver you want from:
http://www.oracle.com/

Or you can get it from your oracle installation:
{ORACLE_HOME}\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar

Then run the following maven command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile={Path/to/your/ojdbc.jar} -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

This should install it in your local repository so when you reference it as user640378 states above it should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="dataSourceName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
    <property name="username" value="hr" />
    <property name="password" value="hr" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Maybe you should provide a bit of a longer explanation to your answer